# is it possible to run javascript one time only?

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I'm looking for one time clicking solution , i want javascript to load only one time in life for every member of my website

when member of my website will interact with javascript for example by clicking yes or no in browser i want this script not to load again in his browser

Comment: How do you identify your users?

Comment: Store it in a cookie/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

This is something that's best to do on the server side. For example, if you have a database field for users that is something like "Last Login" and you only load the script if that value is null.

It depends on the info you have on your users. This is not advisable to solve in js.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cookies, however clunky that may seem. Create a cookie when he presses the button in the form and just test for that cookie when he visits each page. Do remember that people with cookies turned off will keep receiving it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies or local/session Storage for this...something along these lines

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('isNewUser')) {
    localStorage.setItem('isNewUser', false);
    alert('new user');
          //insert whatever you want to do the first time a user visits your page      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do what you are asking. How are you going to uniquely identify your users? What's gonna happen if your users access the page from within another browser, another IP etc.?

The only somewhat reliable way of doing it is through a registration system which would require your users to log in before using your one-time functionality. Once they log in the functionality (button) should only be available through a server-side request or an asynchronous (ajax) request through JavaScript.

Even then its usually a lost battle to prevent people from creating multiple accounts etc.